# Defining new datum in ArcGIS with seven parameter translation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, datum, translation

Is there a way to define a new datum in ArcGIS with seven parameter translation?

Comment: No, the Projection Engine is a DLL. Only Esri developers can add a datum.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is very much possible to create a new datum in ArcGIS, and then create a 7-p transformation to convert to/from that datum.  Please see example workflow here for a fictional case:

Step 1. In the coordinate system tab select New>Geographic Coordinate System:
 [image: Add new GCS]

Step 2. Enter the details for the new GCS including datum name and spheroid information:
[image: enter datum info]

Step 3. Once the new datum and GCS has been created, select the Transformations button and then choose the **from** and **to** GCS.  Press **New** to create the new transformation:
[image: new transformation]

Step 4. Select the transformation type and enter the details:
[image: 7p transformation]

Step 5. The new datum is ready for use.  If you need it projected then create a new projected CRS and change the GCS to use the new datum:
[image: New projection with custom datum]

Also see: [ESRI Create Custom Geographic Transformation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-custom-geographic-transformation.htm)

Answer (score -1):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232671/define-a-new-datum-in-arcgis#comment361942_232671):

> No, the Projection Engine is a DLL. Only Esri developers can add a datum.